# Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on null in /src/app/code/local/ITC/JLimoPayment/Model/Payment.php on line 87

Tags: magento-1.9

When I load my layout I catch exception. My layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <layout version="0.1.0"> <agentdeposit_success_success>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/finalizeorder.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="agentdeposit/success" name="agentdeposit_success" template="agentdeposit/success_form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </agentdeposit_success_success> </layout>
```

My controller:

```
<?php
class Payment_AgentDeposit_SuccessController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action
{

    public function successAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

and my block:

```
<?php
class Payment_AgentDeposit_Block_Success extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container
{

    protected $_quote;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My exception on the photo. 
I broke my head. What it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend your block class to

```
Mage_Payment_Block_Form
```

and not to

```
Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container
```